# R - remove NA in character data with complete.cases

Tags: r, dataframe, character, na

I want to remove rows containing NA values in any column of the data frame "addition" using

```
a <- addition[complete.cases(addition), ]
```

and

```
a <- addition[!is.na(addition)]
```

and

```
a <- na.omit(addition)
```

but the NAs remain. I have also tried restricting `complete.cases` to the only column containing some NAs.
I have found out that they are not identified at all:

```
   which(is.na(addition))
    integer(0)
```

The data frame "addition" looks like this (NA is the 4th column on Row 1211):

```
row.names lemma pos derlemma derpos handannotated
11 akvizice N perform_akvizice V 1
1211 diagnóza N NA V 1
1221 dialýza N dialyzovat V 1
1241 díkuvzdání N perform_díkuvzdání V 1
```

I only get the NAs removed using this:

```
a <- addition[which(addition$derlemma != "NA"), ]
```

Do I use the complete.cases function or annotated "NA" in a wrong way, or have I possibly messed up something in the R Studio user options?

Many thanks for any support.

Working with RStudio Version 0.98.1028, Win 7 Professional 64x.

---

LATER:
Thanks to the answers below I realized that "NA" in character variables is not interpreted as "not available" but as just a string.

I had created the entire data set in R and subsequently added "NA" strings (without the quotes) into some cells in the Data Editor within RStudio. Therefore I failed to specify for R that "NA" means NA.

When I saved the data frame as a .csv and loaded it again with read.table(), I was able to specify na.strings = "NA" and complete.cases() worked. Many thanks again to all the advisors!

Comment: Could you provide a subset of your data your having trouble with ?

Comment: It seems that what you believe is `NA` (see `?NA`) in your data, in fact is a character string "NA". `na.omit(yourdataset)` works if you have `NA`. Depending on how you have coded your missing values in the data you read to R, the `na.strings` argument in `read.table` may be relevant here.

Comment: If you are using the Import Dataset tool in RStudio, it has an na.strings field that states how missing values are encoded - if your raw data file is as above, the default `NA` should work fine.

Comment: Agree with Henrik. `addition[complete.cases(addition), ]` should work if your data contained `NA` instead of `"NA"`. You need to fix something upstream. If you loaded your data using `read.table`, make sure to use the default value `na.strings = "NA"`. Or maybe you created your data programmatically, in which case, make sure to fill those non-available values with `NA` instead of `"NA"`.